# RefreshControl with ScrollView moves screen content down with each refresh

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've got a screen with a ScrollView that has a refreshControl property.
Turns out that when I refresh my screen, the whole content of the screen moves a few positions down. If I refresh again it keeps going down and so on.

[image]
[image]

This screenshots are taken right before refreshing and right after. As you see after refreshing some space was added on top of the screen. Why?

Here's what's inside my render function:

```
render() {
  if(this.state.isLoading || this.state.user === null) {
   // IF I PUT RETURN NULL HERE IT WORKS FINE,AND THE CONTENT DOESNT GO DOWN
    return(<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{alignItems: "center", flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Spinner isVisible={true} size={100} type={'Pulse'} color={'#013773'}/>
      <DropdownAlert ref={ref => this.dropDownAlertRef = ref} /> 
    </ScrollView>);
  }
  else {
    return (
      <ScrollView
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
          refreshing={this.state.isLoading}
          onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
        />
      }>
        <View style={styles.whiteContainer}>
          <View style={{backgroundColor: colors.white,paddingVertical: 10, borderStyle: 'solid', borderColor: colors.black}}>
              <Text style={{fontStyle: 'italic', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize:20, marginLeft:20, color: colors.grey}}>
                Mis donaciones
              </Text>
          </View>
          {this.state.myDonations.length > 0 ? 
          <Carousel
            ref={(c) => { this._carousel = c; }}
            data={this.state.myDonations}
            renderItem={this._renderDonation}
            sliderWidth={SLIDER_WIDTH}
            itemWidth={ITEM_WIDTH2}
            inactiveSlideShift={0}
            onSnapToItem={(index) => this.setState({ index })}
            scrollInterpolator={scrollInterpolator}
            slideInterpolatedStyle={animatedStyles}
            useScrollView={true}
            />: 
            <Text style={{fontStyle: 'italic', alignSelf: 'center', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize:20, marginTop:20, marginBottom: 40, color: colors.grey}}>
            ¡Nada para mostrar!
          </Text>}
        </View>
        {this.state.user.category === "Voluntario" ? 
        <View style={styles.whiteContainer2}>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: colors.white,paddingVertical:10, borderStyle: 'solid', borderColor: colors.black}}>
            <Text style={{fontStyle: 'italic', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize:20, marginLeft:20, color: colors.grey}}>
              Mis entregas
            </Text>
        </View>
        {this.state.myDeliveries.length > 0 ? 
        <Carousel
        ref={(c) => { this._carousel = c; }}
        data={this.state.myDeliveries}
        renderItem={this._renderDelivery}
        sliderWidth={SLIDER_WIDTH}
        itemWidth={ITEM_WIDTH2}
        inactiveSlideShift={0}
        onSnapToItem={(index) => this.setState({ index })}
        scrollInterpolator={scrollInterpolator}
        slideInterpolatedStyle={animatedStyles}
        useScrollView={true}
      /> : <Text style={{fontStyle: 'italic', alignSelf: 'center', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize:20, marginTop:20, marginBottom: 40, color: colors.grey}}>
      ¡Nada para mostrar!
    </Text>}
      </View>
        : null}
        <View style={styles.whiteContainer2}>
          <View style={{backgroundColor: colors.white, paddingVertical:10, borderStyle: 'solid', borderColor: colors.black}}>
              <Text style={{fontStyle: 'italic', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize:20, marginLeft:20, color: colors.grey}}>
                Pedidos
              </Text>
          </View>
          {this.state.requests.length > 0 ? 
          <Carousel
              ref={(c) => { this._carousel = c; }}
              data={this.state.requests}
              renderItem={this._renderRequest}
              sliderWidth={SLIDER_WIDTH}
              itemWidth={ITEM_WIDTH}
              inactiveSlideShift={0}
              onSnapToItem={(index) => this.setState({ index })}
              scrollInterpolator={scrollInterpolator}
              slideInterpolatedStyle={animatedStyles}
              useScrollView={true}
            /> : <Text style={{fontStyle: 'italic', alignSelf: 'center', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize:20, marginTop:20, marginBottom: 40, color: colors.grey}}>
            ¡Nada para mostrar!
          </Text>}
        </View>
        <DropdownAlert ref={ref => this.dropDownAlertRef = ref} /> 
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

_onRefresh looks like this:

```
_onRefresh = () => {   
  this.setState({
    user: null,
    isLoading: true
  });
}
```

isLoading is later set on false when methods inside componentDidUpdate finish loading.

I'm importing RefreshControl and ScrollView from "react-native": "~0.61.4".

Update: As you see inside my render method I got an if-else statement. Turns out if I put return null instead of my spinner inside of the first block, the problem is solved. Why?

Comment: _this.onRefresh(); needs to be reset again onRefresh success as showing example https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.23/refreshcontrol

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani I updated my question. I think I'm resetting it properly.

Comment: request your code after isLoading = true then you resetting isLoading = false after work done like _onRefresh() {
    this.setState({isLoading: true});
    fetchData().then(() => {
      this.setState({isLoading: false});
    });
  }

Comment: When I set isLoading to true, that triggers the componentDidUpdate method. Then inside of componentDidUpdate I call some other methods which end up setting isLoading to false.

Comment: Try putting your DidUpdate code in _onRefresh() as I showed you. Lets try

Comment: I just tried commenting my whole  componentDidUpdate and setting a timer inside onRefresh and then setting isLoading back to false. Same thing keeps happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue.
As you see I had a conditional if-else statement in my render method.
Turns out I had to add RefreshControl to the ScrollView of the first block of the statement as well.

```
render() {
  if(this.state.isLoading || this.state.user === null) {
    return(
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{alignItems: "center", flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}
    refreshControl={
      <RefreshControl
        refreshing={false}
        onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
      />
    }>
      ...
    </ScrollView>);
  }
  else {
    return (
      <ScrollView
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
          refreshing={this.state.isLoading}
          onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
        />
      }>
        ...
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```